# Is ECDH(E) Key Exchange FIPS 140-2 compliant?

Tags: elliptic-curves, diffie-hellman, fips-140

We have read dozens of documents now - some that contradict each other - and cannot find a solid source of truth. Does FIPS 140-2 compliance allow for the use of elliptic curve cryptography as a key exchange for TLS communication? ECDH and ECDHE - if so, which P-xxx key sizes?

Comment: What are you trying to do? As far as I can see FIPS 140-2 has nothing to do with TLS communication. The first step should be figuring out which document is relevant for your case.

Comment: TLS offers a list of cryptographic algorithms to choose from. And Fips requires that you only use algorithms listed in their standards. The intersection of both are the FIPS allowed TLS modes. A bit googling should also reveal that.

Comment: Yes it does, the following is for a specific device. In section 3.3.4 here http://csrc.nist.gov/groups/STM/cmvp/documents/140-1/140sp/140sp2670.pdf

Answer (score 2):

If you look at the FIPS Implementation Guidelines for FIPS-140-2 here
https://csrc.nist.gov/csrc/media/projects/cryptographic-module-validation-program/documents/fips140-2/fips1402ig.pdf

In section D.8 Key Agreements, you will find the recommendations.
This recommendation points to NIST SP-800-56A, where in Appendix D, there is a table of  "Approved ECC Curves and FFC Safe-prime Groups."

SP-800-56A has references to FIPS186-4 and RFC4492 (for TLS) and RFC 5903 (for IKE).
These references should be enough to justify use of ECDH in a FIPS140-2 approved device.